# Lista ordenada com próximo elemento à direita quando não couber

Tags: html, css, css3, menu, submenu

Estou criando um menu onde terei vários botões. Para alinhar os botões eu uso uma lista ordenada simples. Quero saber se existe alguma forma de, quando não couber mais botões dentro da altura máxima do submenu, estes pularem para a direita.

Comment: poderia dar mais detalhes, mostrar o seu código? Temos um recurso interessante semelhante ao jsFiddle agora nos posts so [pt.so], daí podemos ver o seu código e ajudar a conseguir o efeito desejado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apenas com CSS é possível recorrendo às propriedades [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

```css
/**CSS**/    
ol{
 height:100px;
 overflow:hidden;
 background: red;
 -webkit-column-count: 2;  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
 -moz-column-count: 2;     -moz-column-gap: 15px;
 column-count: 2;          column-gap: 15px;
}
ol li{
 background: yellow;
 line-height:18px;
 margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

```html
/**HTML**/
<ol>
<li>Opção 1</li>
<li>Opção 2</li>
<li>Opção 3</li>
<li>Opção 4</li>
<li>Opção 5</li>
<li>Opção 6</li>
<li>Opção 7</li>
<li>Opção 8</li>
</ol>
```

**Nota:** As formatações dadas é para ilustração visual, o importante é definir `overflow:hidden;` no contentor e aplicar as propriedades `columns`.

[image: Ilustração do resultado no JSFiddle]

Comment: Bacana, também não conhecia essa propriedade.